# The first network request is incredibly slow

Tags: networking, 18.04

I use Ubuntu on the server owned by my hosting provider and the first network request is incredibly slow - for example, `ping` or a network request to remote server from my Java application. It is no exception that I wait 10-12 secs to start pinging and get the first response from the remote server (ping delay and response time is normal - expected amount of milliseconds), next responses are as fast as expected.

The provider's admin told me that I have to update the version of the operating system that the problem may be due to this - which comes to me as the most complicated possible option.

I am not a system admin and therefore I do not know what information are need to diagnostis the problem - I will be happy to add what will be needed.

Edit - added some output from time measurement of ping:

```
....@vm27884:~$ time ping kms.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
PING kms.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com (54.239.54.221) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from kms.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com (54.239.54.221): icmp_seq=1 ttl=230 time=19.3 ms
64 bytes from kms.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com (54.239.54.221): icmp_seq=2 ttl=230 time=19.2 ms
64 bytes from kms.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com (54.239.54.221): icmp_seq=3 ttl=230 time=19.4 ms
^C
--- kms.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 9031ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.261/19.358/19.464/0.083 ms

real    0m17.535s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.002s
```

Comment: Is this a virtual computer? if it is then the delay probably reflects the time it takes to get your vm up and running on the server, it might be swapped out.   How long does it take before the "first" network request is slow again?

Comment: Yes, it's VPS and I asked my provider. Now it took approx. 30min (?) - see measurement report I added.

Comment: @SEWTGIYWTKHNTDS I just upgraded to 20.04.2.

Comment: Perhaps some device between your system (your wireless NIC, your router, ...) is in Power Saving mode (Wake-On-LAN), and takes a while to wake. 2nd and subsequent packets, it's awake. Something in your VPS setup is taking too ling.

Comment: If it helps, whenever I try and ping kms.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com (I think this is your vm) it ALWAYS responds instantly, no delays.  Sounds as though the problem is not with your VM.

Comment: No, it is a ping to remote AWS KMS server. My VM is not hosted by Amazon, but I use a local provider in Czech Republic.

Comment: OK, If you ping the remove server using it's IP address rather than a name is the delay still there?  It sounds like the delay is caused by the dns lookup, perhaps you have a bad dns server entry and it has to timeout before trying a server that returns the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting a response from your first two DNS resolvers. Take a look at your /etc/resolv.conf.

By default, linux goes through nameservers from top to bottom (very repeatable) and has a timeout of 5 seconds before attempting the next. If you're lucky, it's as simple as updating resolv.conf to be valid DNS servers. If they are already well-known DNS servers like 8.8.8.8 (google's DNS server), then you'll need to start poking around your network to understand why those requests/responses are being dropped (firewall rules, bad routing, etc).

How am I so certain that this is the problem? Because I help run a network where we block external DNS (somewhat common for companies that run DNS filtering as a first line of defense). Anyone who overrides the DHCP-provided DNS endpoints complain about a 5 second or 10 second delay. If you happen to be on a network that does something similar, you'll need to either stop overriding DHCP (your network admins would prefer that), or update the values to point to their provided/allowed DNS server.